# Angular: $http.post() not called

Tags: angularjs, post

I am using $http to post data to server.

There are two OPTIONS requestMethod calls before making a POST request.

However, the POST request is not made sometimes.

As I am updating html on return of this call, the page hangs.

```
 $http({
       url: scope.Settings.url,
               method: "POST",
                data:data,
                withCredentials: true
            }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                setBusyState(false);
                scope.rModel = scope.search;
                scope.Results = data.data;
            }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
                scope.Results = [];
                setBusyState(false);
            });
```

EDIT: This does not happen always. Only a few times.

This appears to happen only in Chrome, whereas it is fine in IE

Comment: Have you checked for any console errors and monitored the network tab of chrome browser or tried to see what fiddler is reporting?If so share those updates.

Comment: Also angularjs caches the request in IE so always use  `app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');
        $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
        if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
        }        
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
    }
    ]);`

Comment: Looks like CORS issue. Have you checked the console?

Comment: Also make sure your endpoint is responding. This can give the impression that the req is not being made.

Comment: I checked Fiddler. It shows me only two OPTIONS request. No POST request is made. Also no console errors appear

Comment: Can you post server side code?

Comment: Server side returns me proper results. I checked it with POSTMAN.

Comment: @Ajinkya pls try my second comment.it could be caching.check in your app.config.

Comment: @Navoneel I tried that. It throws me error                                               `Unknown provider: requestInterceptorProvider <- requestInterceptor <- $http <- TemplateCacheSvc`  How should I take care of this dependency?

Comment: Further looking into it. I found that those Pre-Flight OPTIONS requests are a way of asking permissions for the actual request, before making the actual request

Comment: so you must have a file called `requestInterceptorProvider.js` .if not skip that line.

Comment: @Navoneel It seems to work. Can u please explain me what the code does exactly? Thanks

Comment: @Ajinkya see my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What angular does in chrome is, it makes OPTIONS request.

These Pre-Flight OPTIONS requests are a way of asking permissions for the actual request, before making the actual request.

So, as a work around, adding **headers to the request** solves the problem.

```
$http({
    url: scope.Settings.url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    withCredentials: true
}).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    setBusyState(false);
    scope.rModel = scope.search;
    scope.Results = data.data;
}, function(data, status, headers, config) {
    scope.Results = [];
    setBusyState(false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with AngularJS where it caches the subsequent http requests so if you have multiple http requests lined up you would sometime experience that some of the calls are not actually made.I have mainly seen this issue of aggressive caching in IE.

To overcome this issue you need to apply some sort of global settings which will prevent the http requests from getting cached.The ideal place of doing this in angular is `$httpProvider`.

Basically you are setting different header parameters with the appropriate values.

Related code from app.config

```
appConfig.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {       
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = <set a time>;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}
]);
```